# Apply background color to the whole html page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]I have an HTML page where I have a div called `container`, I'm trying to use bootstrap here. Inside the container, I have a div called `row`. When I try to apply a background color to the div the color is applied only to the div content and spans only the width and not the height. I'm trying to apply the background to the hello world site and I want it to cover the whole page.

Here is the code.

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}
.row {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homePage.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row"> Hello World! </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1st: The html element has a default margin that you have to deal with every time you write a page.

2nd:You may not want use jsfiddle to test code when using bootstrap css (or any other library for that sake). As the JSFiddle code is run before the bootstrap code.

3rd: Try this:

```css
body,html{
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
}
html{
    background-color: gray;
}

.container {
    padding: 1em;
    max-width:750px;
    min-height:100vh;
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:aquamarine;
}

.row {
    margin:0;
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row"> Hello World! </div>
      <div class="row"> Hello , I am World! </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: doesn't work. The gaps on the side are still getting covered.

Comment: Edited my answer to fit the new info.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply it to the body.

```
 body{
    background-color: red;
 }
```

Comment: that works. But if you run the code you would notice gaps either side of the page,if I use body tag that gaps also gets covered.

Comment: So is it running as expected?

Comment: No it's not. Check out the fiddle I have added in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need.

```css
.container {
  margin-left:-20px;
  padding-left:30px;
   margin-right:-20px;
   background-color: darkgray;
  }

.row {
    background-color: darkgray;
}

body{
    background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> Hello World! </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the container to cover from top to bottom and set the gaps that you need left and right:

```
.container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 10px; /* Gap left */
            right: 10px; /* Gap right */
            bottom: 0px;
            background-color: black;
        }
```

Comment: There should be no reason to use absolute positioned elements here

Answer (score 1):

May this one you need:

```css
html,body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.row {
    background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> Hello World! </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems nice to me:

```css
html {
  background-color: darkgray
}
.row {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/homePage.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">Hello World! Here goes some content</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```